# A word that describes someone who 'sees/brings out the good in others'?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

The person doesn't have to be good themselves, but they can bring the good out of others. The word doesn't have to be an english word, I just want to know if such a word exists.

Ex. Beauty with the Beast. Durga with Asura(Asura's Wrath, not the religious scripture). The 3 ghosts in the Christmas Story with Scrooge.

Comment: Durga with Asura is a bad example here. Durga **vanquishes** or **annihilates** the Asura.

Comment: In Joseph Campbell's theory of mythological archetypes, the spirits in *A Christmas Carol* are Mentors. Belle is more of a Hero.

Answer (score 2):

One would most likely use "complements."

By the way, in literature, a "foil" is a character that complements another, such as in the case of Sancho and Don Quixote.

Comment: I thought that at first, but that's more for if something goes together well with something else. I mean that someone can bring out the good in others, make someone want to act for the better, you know? I guess another example being, say someone was just a bad person(druggie, steals, lies, etc.). What would be a word to call someone who makes them want to change their life around.

Answer (score -1):

The closest noun I can think of is "counselor." Or, perhaps, "friend." It depends on whether there's an element of caring, so whatever noun comes closest, depending on context.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.